# Why do I get "Could not find mail-2.2.9.1 in any of the sources" after updated Ruby and Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, bundle, rvm

I recently updated my Ruby version to 1.9.2 through RVM. (And, is it normal that I have to use the command `rvm use 1.9.2` EVERY TIME when starting the terminal?).

I deleted some Rails files I shouldn't have, so I reinstalled Rails. However, I still get this error when trying to generate controllers:

> > Could not find mail-2.2.9.1 in any of the sources
> >
> > Try running `bundle install`.

Running `bundle install` solves the problem for the moment, but I get the same error when starting another project.

Comment: Issue the command `rvm --default use 1.9.2` once, and it will remember to use the ruby 1.9.2 as default.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use an rvmrc file.  it tells rvm which ruby version / gemset to use.  read:

https://rvm.io/workflow/rvmrc/

Comment: You don't *need* to use a .rvmrc file. I just use `rvm use 1.9.2 --default`